Tearing in Tkinter while scrolling
I'm experiencing pretty bad tearing while scrolling around in Tkinter. My code so far is a bit complex, so I'll try to explain it by words: I'm using a scrollable Canvas which has a grid of Text elements. Basically, it's a scrollable table. Using the Text widget is important, I'll have to do some text highlighting later so each cell in the table should really be a Text widget.
It looks like this while scrolling: 
It is just 30 rows with 5 columns, so 150 text widgets in a canvas, and the tearing looks pretty bad. I thought it would be able to handle this. Is there maybe some "magic" one-liner fix for this, maybe a different theme or something trivial?
EDITI have now conjured a solution with just a single tk.Text widget which is impersonating a table. Here is the code.
import tkinter as tk
import random

def insert_values():
    global text

    # clear first
    text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    pad_right = 1
    columns = [{"width":20},
               {"width":15},
               {"width":40},
               {"width":20},
               {"width":30}]
    
    
    text.tag_configure("white", background="white")
    text.tag_configure("separator", background="SystemButtonFace")
    text.tag_configure("highlight_something", background="blue")
    text.tag_configure("underline", underline=True, underlinefg='black')

    current_line_number_digit = 1
    current_line_number = str(current_line_number_digit)
    lines_written = 0
    while lines_written < 40:        
        current_left_sum = 0
        
        # insert white background tags for columns and separators
        for col_index, column in enumerate(columns):
            value_to_write = "Line " + str(lines_written) + ". " + random.sample(["wooo", "eeeee", "meeeoooowww", "too loooooooooong foooooooor thiiiiiiiiiiiiissssss haha"], 1)[0]
            if len(value_to_write) >= column["width"]:
                value_to_write = value_to_write[0:column["width"]]
            else:
                value_to_write = value_to_write + " "*(column["width"]-len(value_to_write))

            text.insert(current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum), value_to_write)
            text.tag_add("white", current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum), current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum+column["width"]))
            text.tag_add("underline", current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum), current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum+column["width"]))

            # add tag if needed
            if col_index == 2:
                text.tag_add("highlight_something", current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum+3), current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum+12))
                
            current_left_sum+=column["width"]
            
            if col_index != len(columns)-1:
                text.insert(current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum), " "*pad_right)
                text.tag_add("separator", current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum), current_line_number + "." + str(current_left_sum+pad_right))
                current_left_sum+=pad_right
        lines_written+=1
            
        # put a new line before the end
        if lines_written < 40:
            text.insert(tk.END, "\n")
            current_line_number_digit+=1
            current_line_number = str(current_line_number_digit)

        

    
    return


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x800")

global text
text = tk.Text(root, width=129, font=("Consolas", 12), background="SystemButtonFace", spacing1=10) ## MUST BE FIXED SIZED FONT!!!! (MONOSIZED FONT)
text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
text.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")


vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
text["yscrollcommand"] = vscrollbar.set
hscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.xview, orient='horizontal')
hscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
text["xscrollcommand"] = hscrollbar.set

button = tk.Button(root, command=insert_values, width=20, text="Insert something")
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

print(root.cget("bg"))
root.mainloop()

This does seem to scroll without stuttering. I can't really figure out how to make a pretty vertical border for the column, for horizontal I have underlining. So I put a layer between, it appears a bit too thick compared to the underline.
Also, there seems to be an issue that when I select a text, it turns invisible if I use white background. I hope there is maybe an option for that.

It is a 30x5 table, I didn't think I was asking too much from Tkinter to make that work. BTW if you edited my post, it seems now the image link is broken.

Sorry if the image link is broken (it still shows up for me), feel free to revert the change. Tkinter is quite slow and 150 widgets is a lot. Why don't you emulated the all of the widgets with a single tk.Text or tk.Canvas?. I suggest waiting for someone more experienced than me to answer this question.

It's hard to tell from a picture but what value did you give the Canvas["yscrollincrement"]?

@Derek: I don't have any mention of "yscrollincrement" in my code. There is just "yscrollcommand" that is set to scrollbar. My code for scrolling is basically this https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/ As I understand, this is the only way to make scrolling over a Frame.

The xscrollincrement and yscrollincrement should be defined in your canvas object as an integer equal to the amount you want your scrollbar to move the canvas.

I kept these at their default values, which are 0 it seems. With big ones, there is less tearing, but it doesn't seem so smooth anymore.

I added a bit of code, this does seem to work best, it is just a single tk.Text which is supposed to act like a table.

You need to measure a single Text object dimensions in points then set xscrollincrement and yscrollincrement. It usually takes a little fiddling to get it exactly right since there maybe extra padding around objects. (borderwidth, highlightthickness, etc)

I just ran your code and it scrolls without any artifacts.

This code I added isn't what I used originally. Originally I had 150 Text widgets on the screen separately, maybe that was a bad idea. This code I posted is just a single text widget, but then it's a bit more complex to put values in so that it looks like a table.
